# Insert parent and Child in Springboot through Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to save a record and its child list with spring boot through postman in a One-to-Many relationship. The child list is  saved but they don't take the Id of the parent automatically. How can i force the child to automatically take the id of the parent in Post Request In Postman?

Parent Class

```
package fdsa.edu.pnu.Model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "Concours")
public class Concours implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 10)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PNU_CONCOURS_ID_GENERATOR")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "PNU_CONCOURS_ID_GENERATOR", strategy = "native")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "DateDebut", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private java.util.Date DateDebut;

    @Column(name = "DateFin", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private java.util.Date DateFin;

    @Column(name = "Description", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "concours",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity = fdsa.edu.pnu.Model.PlannificationConcours.class)

    private List<PlannificationConcours> plannificationConcourses;


}
```

Child Class

````
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "PlannificationConcours")
public class PlannificationConcours implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 10)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PNU_PLANNIFICATIONCONCOURS_ID_GENERATOR")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = "PNU_PLANNIFICATIONCONCOURS_ID_GENERATOR", strategy = "native")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = fdsa.edu.pnu.Model.Concours.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(value = {@JoinColumn(name = "ConcoursID", referencedColumnName = "ID")}, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ConcoursPlannificationConCours"))
    private Concours concours;

    @Column(name = "`Date`", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private java.util.Date Date;

    @Column(name = "Quotation", nullable = true, length = 10)
    private double quotation;

    @Column(name = "NoteDePassage", nullable = true, length = 10)
    private double noteDePassage;
    
}```

Screen Shote where the Id of the parent is null
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlnhP.png
````

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to reach it. And this is the minimal setting to do it:

1. **Unidirectional**

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Concours {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "concours_id") // this line will play the role that passes the parent's id to its children
    private List<PlannificationConcours> plannificationConcourses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class PlannificationConcours {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}
```

```java
@Test
void saveConcours() {
    Concours concours = new Concours();
    concours.setPlannificationConcourses(List.of(new PlannificationConcours(), new PlannificationConcours()));
    this.concoursRepository.save(concours);
}
```

This's all you need to propagate the parent's id. But the child won't have the reference to its parent by this way.

2. **Bidirectional**

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Concours {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "concours" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // mappedBy will create a bidirectional relation for us
    private List<PlannificationConcours> plannificationConcourses = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPlannificationConcours(PlannificationConcours child) {
        child.setConcours(this); // and don't forget to set the parent instance to the child
        this.plannificationConcourses.add(child);
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class PlannificationConcours {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Concours concours;
}
```

```java
@Test
void saveConcours() {
    Concours concours = new Concours();
    concours.addPlannificationConcours(new PlannificationConcours());
    concours.addPlannificationConcours(new PlannificationConcours());
    this.concoursRepository.save(concours);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, i still get the null value in the foreign key.  Are you able to  test it in postman and share your code?

Comment: Yes, basically you can try my code. For **Bidirectional** don't forget whenever you add a `PlannificationConcours`, set the `Concours` for it as I mentioned above `child.setConcours(this);`. 
Another thing is, `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` in your application.properties(application.yml) in order to check whether it has a sql query to update parent's id in children or not.

Comment: This is what you will see after you run the Bidirectional `@Test` above. You can notice that firstly, it will insert your  `Concours` and secondly, it will insert your `PlannificationConcours` with the `concours_id`
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        concours
        default 
    values
        
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        plannification_concours
        (concours_id) 
    values
        (?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        plannification_concours
        (concours_id) 
    values
        (?)

Comment: The Parent and the child are created according to the sql noticication below but the the relationship is not applied. Hibernate: select nextval ('pnu_concours_id_generator')
Hibernate: select nextval ('pnu_plannificationconcours_id_generator')
Hibernate: insert into concours (date_debut, date_fin, description, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into plannification_concours ("date", concours_id, note_de_passage, quotation, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Do you call the addPlannificationConcours's method somewhere in the service?

Comment: I saw your hibernate log said: insert into plannification_concours ("date", concours_id, note_de_passage, quotation, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?). It means that it's already spread the parent's id to your child entities, right? About **the relationship is not applied.**, you mean the foreign key, don't you? Have you had that `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` in your configuration file. This property will automatically update your tables (in your case: creating a foreign key for you) or you have to do it manually.